# Restoring Anaconda command prompt path

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

After installing pytorch,the anaconda command prompt path has been changed. The pytorch installation seems to have changed the anaconda command prompt path.How can one restore the path?
[Snapshot of my anaconda command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUxJi.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Comment: a simple conda deactivate will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux, anaconda by default get's installed in your /home/{username}/anaconda3 directory

open your .bashrc file:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

Than paste this:

```
export PATH=/home/{username}/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Replace {username} with your username

First check if anaconda3 exists in your home directory

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am on windows. I found that after installing pytorch this problem occurs. So what should I do on windows to overcome this problem

Comment: Find the anaconda installation directory on your machine, copy the directory path and add it to your environment variable.
-Search for "View advanced system setting" from start menu
-Click on environment variable"
-add the copied anaconda directory to your PATH variable there.

Comment: thanks for the reply but the path was automatically changed after installation of the pytorch library and bydefault anaconda doesnot add to the path variable I think, so adding it would only be a work around not a solution to my actual problem